# How to make react-admin resource route default to show instead of edit?

Tags: react-admin

The react-admin docs explain the default routing for resources as:

- `/posts/:id` maps to `PostEdit`
- `/posts/:id/show` maps to `PostShow`

I'd like my app to default to viewing, and only allow editing if the user clicks the edit icon.  However the default for all the reference links is to point to `/resource/:id`.

Is there a way to swap the routing such that `/resource/:id` maps to Show and `/resource/:id/edit` is used for Edit?  Or maybe change the reference links to `/resource/:id/show`?

Comment: its mapping as per standard API routing best practice, why would you want to change that?  if you want the non-standard /posts/:id to map to show, then change the routing on the api side.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly the thing you are looking for, but default actions can be switched, so click on item can lead to `show` instead of `edit`:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#the-datagrid-component

```
export const PostList = (props) => (
    <List {...props}>
        <Datagrid rowClick="show">
            ...
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

Comment: that's not a solution. If I manually enter /{resource}/{id} on the address bar it sould route to the show page and not the edit page.

Answer (score 1):

Reference links can be set to reference "show" by add `link="show"` to the `ReferenceField`.

See https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/247#issuecomment-287819508

Comment: Actually it should be `link="show"` instead of `linkType="show"`, because `The 'linkType' prop is deprecated and should be named to 'link' in <ReferenceField />`.
Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create some custom routes matching your needs redirecting to custom Create/Show components like

```
const customRoutes = [
  <Route key="editPost" exact path="/posts/:id" component={PostEdit} />,
  <Route key="showPost" exact path="/posts/:id/show" component={PostShow} />,
];

function App() {
  return (
    <Admin
      ...
      customRoutes={customRoutes}
    >
    ...
    </Admin>
  )
}
```

Source: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Admin.html#customroutes